# ServiceStack Authorization: Permitting Repeated Emails

Tags: authentication, servicestack

we're using SS4 and would like to set it so that unique emails are not enforced (we have some customers who require the ability to repeat emails for different users).

Demis had mentioned that it's configurable, but a quick glance at the code doesn't reveal what to do to relax the requirement that every account has a unique email.

It looks like maybe we need to mess around with the RegistrationValidator?

is there a sample in the SS code anywhere that shows changing the validation rules for account registering to permit duplicate email addresses to be used?

Comment: OK, so to summarize the answer from @mythz below: Leave Email blank and use PrimaryEmail as your email property, and SS4 will permit you to duplicate emails all you like.  If you put a value in Email, however, it _must be unique._

Answer (score 4):

You can configure it when you register the `AuthFeature` plugin with:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(...) {
    ValidateUniqueEmails = false
});
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. I'm still getting the error  Here's a gist of the code. [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/896f8ae6b69df3c15062)

Comment: I'm looking at the OrmLiteAuthRepository's CreateUserAuth() method, and it looks like it calls AssertNoExistingUser() unconditionally, which checks for unique emails unconditionally. ValidateUniqueEmails doesn't appear to enter into it. Am I misreading that? [link](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/f3362880beead295a0b3d4d51455b3f514417b73/src/ServiceStack.Server/Auth/OrmLiteAuthRepository.cs)

Comment: @gizmoboy Yeah if this is for the Credentials (i.e. UserName/Password) Provider where Email is the UserName than that needs to be unique. The ValidateUniqueEmails was to allow AuthProviders with existing Email addresses through.

Comment: So then it is not possible to create users who have duplicated emails without substantially rewriting the AuthRepo? That's what we did in 3.x, but I was hoping that 4.x would allow us to eliminate some custom code.

Comment: Not when they're used as the UserName, there's a [Primary Email](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/UserAuth.cs#L21) property on UserAuth that can be used to store duplicate email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution in SS 3.x which I assume will work in SS 4.x

AssertNoExistingUser() checks for email uniqueness EVEN if you are trying to use a username as the username on the credentials and not the email.
The simple workaround is to create the user with a null email address (and a valid username).
Once the user is saved you can apply the email back into the user and call  AuthRepo.PatchUserAuth(userAuth)

It will save and you wont have any problems.